# Who's responsibility is it to request pages from the OS as the stack grows?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system

I'm a little foggy on this - but I think the OS needs to be able to keep track of what pages in the virtual address space are in use (or reserved) by a process's threads. For memory explicitly requested by the programmer via [VirtualAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or your OS-equivalent), this is easy. However, as the stack grows/shrinks as the threads execute, the stack spills over a varying number of pages. Clearly the application programmer hasn't requested use of these pages - so who handles the request to the OS? The C-runtime? I don't think the OS can do this automatically. I lack the assembly-knowledge to dump an executable and check myself..

Comment: The OS does it automatically usually. If it sees a page fault near the last stack page, it will assume the stack has to grow and does it.

Comment: You are talking about Windows, it certainly knows how to commit stack pages as it grows.  It allocated the VM space for it and knows about the guard pages.  There is no shrink.

Comment: So is there any runtime intervention? I understand this may differ across OS's

Comment: In theory it is not specified whether the C runtime or the OS intervenes in such a case, but I am in doubt that a real implementation exists where this is done by the runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux being open source, you can look at what it does.
This is from *arch/x86/mm/fault.c*, the `__do_page_fault` function which handles (wait for it) page faults:

```
    vma = find_vma(mm, address);
    if (unlikely(!vma)) {
            bad_area(regs, error_code, address);
            return;
    }

    if (likely(vma->vm_start <= address))
            goto good_area;
    if (unlikely(!(vma->vm_flags & VM_GROWSDOWN))) {
            bad_area(regs, error_code, address);
            return;
    }
    if (error_code & PF_USER) {
            /*
             * Accessing the stack below %sp is always a bug.
             * The large cushion allows instructions like enter
             * and pusha to work. ("enter $65535, $31" pushes
             * 32 pointers and then decrements %sp by 65535.)
             */
            if (unlikely(address + 65536 + 32 * sizeof(unsigned long) < regs->sp)) {
                    bad_area(regs, error_code, address);
                    return;
            }
    }
    if (unlikely(expand_stack(vma, address))) {
            bad_area(regs, error_code, address);
            return;
    }
```

`find_vma` finds the first mapped region which ends above the faulting address. If the fault is above the start address then this is a normal access into an already mapped memory, so nothing to do here (goes to `good_area`).

Otherwise if it's not an area that can grow down, we have an error. What we are left with is an access under an area that can grow down. This is the usual case for a stack.

Next the code checks for the relation of the fault and the stack pointer. Normally local variables are allocated by moving the stack pointer first, but this is not a memory access and thus produces no fault. The stack will be expanded upon the first access, which should therefore be above the stack pointer. The comment `Accessing the stack below %sp is always a bug.` relates to this. Some instructions however temporarily access below the stack pointer, so some allowance is made for that. Also some ABIs utilize a so-called red zone which is a fixed size area under the stack pointer which is freely usable. You can see it considers any access within roughly 64kB of the stack pointer to be a valid access. If everything is in order, the stack is actually expanded.

Comment: I think this explains it about as good as possible. Thanks so much for taking the time to look this code up!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of possibilities - either the stack has a fixed, pre-allocated, size, or it doesn't. In the first case, there's simply nothing to be done. Your program may simply crash as the result of overusing the stack - a stack overflow.

The second case is a bit more complicated, but still solvable. The program loader can create/allocate the initial stack and reserve a bit of its virtual memory space below the stack unmapped. Any accesses to that memory will then cause a memory access error, allowing the runtime to trap/handle that error and allocate additional memory space for the stack.

Comment: You are precisely the person I would have hoped to answer this question Mr. Mac Boot Process. Thanks for your answer, I was thinking along the lines of the latter possibility - didn't even know the fixed-sized case existed in today's world. Thanks again!

Comment: That would make sense, actually. Ps. Can you comment on Jester's comment? I.e. can the OS do this automatically without the runtime's intervention? I imagine this may differ between OS's..

Comment: PSS. I'm also a Canadian living in San Jose :P

Comment: In most cases it's not actually the C runtime that handles the expansion of the stack. Any instruction which touches a memory address close to the current end of the stack invokes a page fault, which is entirely handled by the OS and fully transparent to the user process. The OS would map additional memory and the process would be resumed on the same instruction.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev - that's pretty system specific. But what you describe is what I had in mind, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

The memory segments that the executable image is divided into, which typically include the code-section, the data-section and the stack, are constant.

So when the OS creates a process and loads the executable image into memory, both the size and the base address of each section are well known.

If the process requires more memory than what's currently available, then indeed some of the executable image may be "left outside".

Under such scenario, once the missing part is required for execution, the OS will fetch it into memory.

But as a programmer, you are completely oblivious to that (exactly as you are oblivious to the physical addresses of variables in your code).